# Jboss 4.2 to latest free Jboss version migration

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly

Currently we are using Jboss 4.2 in our production application. 
We want to move our application from this version to latest stable version of Jboss.
Before starting doing this, I have few queries

- Which latest Jboss free version is stable and can be used in
  production ?
- Is there a migration guide available for the same?

PS: I have read many other articles but not got any specific details for my queries.

As per the thread(https://developer.jboss.org/thread/229160?tstart=0), latest Jboss free version is wildfly 8.1 and can be used in production but I want to know that is this version stable or bug free?
i.e. can it be used directly in the production.

Comment: Latest version is 8.2.  It's fairly bug free, considering the technology stack you're coming from (JBoss 4.2, with its EJBs and.. servlets... and not sure what else you might be using)

Comment: Could you please list the technology stack you are using?

Comment: Migration will be relatively straight forward **unless** you're using CMP entity beans. It will be challenging if this is the case.